# How to reload TableVIew Using Model NSObject Class with MVVM

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, tableview

I want to reload TableView without tableview.reloadData() method for that i have used MVVM structure so i have attach model class to storyboard and the issue is that my tableview is reload first and then i get all data how should i solved this issue please help me if any one have a solution !!

This is storyboard model attach

[image]

Model Code :-

```
class MovieModel: Decodable{

    var artistName: String = ""
    var trackName: String = ""

    init(artistName: String, trackName: String){
        self.artistName = artistName
        self.trackName = trackName
    }

}

class ResultModel: Decodable{

    var results = [MovieModel]()

    init(results: [MovieModel]) {
        self.results = results
    }
}
```

My ViewModel File code :-

```
class MovieViewModel: NSObject {

    var artistName: String = ""
    var trackName: String = ""
    var movieModel: MovieModel?
     var movieData = [MovieViewModel]()

    override init() {

    }

    init(movie: MovieModel) {
        self.artistName = movie.artistName
        self.trackName = movie.trackName
    }

    func getData(){
        Service.shareInstance.getAllMovieData { (movie, error) in
            if error == nil{
                self.movieData = movie?.map({return MovieViewModel(movie: $0)}) ?? []
                print(self.movieData)
            }else{
                print("\(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfRow(section:Int) -> Int{
        return movieData.count
    }

    func cellForRow(indexPath: IndexPath) -> MovieViewModel{
        return self.movieData[indexPath.row]
    }


}
```

My ViewController Code :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var movieVM: MovieViewModel?
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            self.movieVM?.getData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movieVM?.numberOfRow(section: section) ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        let movie = movieVM?.cellForRow(indexPath: indexPath)
        cell?.textLabel?.text = movie?.artistName
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = movie?.trackName
        return cell!
    }

}
```

In my case i am not reload tableview all this is done using ModelClass ! Thank You !!

Comment: `movieVM` is declared but not initialized. `getData` is not going to be called.

Comment: I have called getData to viewcontroller it called but it reload first and then it append all the data what should i do now please help